# Visualize summary-statistics with R

Tags: r

My dataset looks similar to the one described here( i have more variables=columns and more observations):

```
dat=cbind(var1=c(100,20,33,400),var2=c(1,0,1,1),var3=c(0,1,0,0))
```

Now I want to create a bargraph with R where on the x axis one see the names of all the variable, and on the y axis the mean of the respective variable.

As a second task it would be great to show not only the mean, also the standard deviation within the same plot.

It would be nice, solving this with gglopt or qplot.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, first, i summarized s=describe(subset1,num.desc=c("mean","sd","valid.n"))
s=s$Numeric
s=data.frame(s)   then i used:ggplot(s,aes(x=variable,y=mean))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") but it doesn't look nice (i know that the scale of the variables is not equal so a barplot may not look so appropriate, but i think of doing the bargraph twice: for dummy and for continous) 
s=cbind(s,variable=rownames(s))

Comment: Have a look at `boxplot(mtcars)` for instance.

Comment: But i need a bargraph

Comment: Did you google `ggplot bar graph`? There are tons of examples and explanations for things like this, such as: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Yes, thanks! But my problem is that i dont have a column which is categorial and could be choosen for the x-axis. I want the columnnames as x-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R:

```
dat <- cbind(var1=c(1,0.20,0.33,4),var2=c(1,0,1,1),var3=c(0,1,0,0))
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)   # get this into a data frame as early as possible
barplot(sapply(dat,mean))
```

[image]

Using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)    # for melt(...)
df <- melt(dat)

ggplot(df, aes(x=variable,y=value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar",color="grey20",fill="lightgreen")+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl",mult=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, the only thin that does't work, is the melt-command: it says: No id variables; using all as measure variables

Comment: Did you convert `dat` to a data frame first?

Comment: but it could be maybe because i loan the library(ggplot2),library(dplyr),library(plyr) and there might be a conflict with this command...

Comment: I doubt it. How did `melt(...)` fail?

Comment: Okay,i see: the function ggplot as you do works, and delivers your given output, but i got the error message after melt(dat) : "No id variables; using all as measure variables"- why is this?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning - but you wouldn't know that from the message... It means that `melt(...)` is expecting a column which contains "id"s. If you provide one, it uses the *other* columns for the values and replicates the id column for each instance of value. But it's not required and if omitted `melt(...)` assumes *all* columns contain values - which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Okay, thats all i need to know! Is there a way not to display warning messages? Great Answer: much detail and human compalition afterwards!! Thanks a lot!! I would give some score but i'm to new for it :(

Comment: The jwewl of the crown would be, if i could create the same plot but grouping the dataset by the second variable( a dummy variable) so that for every other variable there are 2 bars, one for 0 and one for 1? Can you put the code at the quastion, or add it ? Or is it better to make a new one `?